# Does it make sense to use Backbone.js in an existing application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

The situation as it stands is:

- We're using our own services API for all the application logic to save data and validate it
- We're using localstorage instead of cookies for the few variables we need to keep track of (authentication token, etc)

The presentation layer of the app is currently written in vanilla javascript with some Jquery for basic stuff.

Would it make sense to switch to Backbone - and if so, what code would need to be refactored?